# Adding mockito-inline dependecy in pom.xml causing Mockmaker issue

Tags: java, maven, mockito

I am having this problem where including the mockito-inline dependency in my pom.xml causes a problem with Mockmaker when building with Maven 3.8.1. Without the dependency, the build and tests run fine however.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The following code normally passes the integration test without any issues unless the above dependency is included.

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

class StarterServiceIT extends AbstractIT {

  @Autowired
  private StarterService service;

  @Test
  void canLoadSpringContext() {
    assertThat(service).isNotNull();
  }

}
```

The error is as follows:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.068 s <<< FAILURE! - in beta.service.StarterServiceIT
canLoadSpringContext  Time elapsed: 0.06 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in java.lang.CompoundEnumeration@7b7ef483
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 

Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.

It appears as if your JDK does not supply a working agent attachment mechanism.
Java               : 16
JVM vendor name    : Homebrew
JVM vendor version : 16.0.1+0
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 16.0.1+0
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 11.5.1

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not self-attach to current VM using external process
```

Doing a `mvn dependency:tree` shows that the dependencies for mockito-inline are parsed properly. Already tried an `mvn dependency:resolve` as well, but it did not help.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< starter:starter.service >---------------------
[INFO] Building Beta Service Starter 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree (default-cli) @ starter.service ---
[INFO] starter:starter.service:jar:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- starter:starter.event-schema:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.15.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.28:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.50:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.50:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.50:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.5-6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.confluent:kafka-protobuf-serializer:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.confluent:kafka-protobuf-provider:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.squareup.wire:wire-schema:jar:3.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:jar:3.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.confluent:kafka-protobuf-types:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.api.grpc:googleapis-common-protos:jar:0.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:0.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:0.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:0.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.confluent:kafka-schema-serializer:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.confluent:common-utils:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.17.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:30.1.1-android:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:compile
[INFO] +- io.opentelemetry.javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.prometheus:simpleclient:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.sentry:sentry-spring-boot-starter:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.sentry:sentry:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.sentry:sentry-spring:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.sentry:sentry-log4j2:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.vavr:vavr:jar:0.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.vavr:vavr-match:jar:0.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-annotations:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-consumer:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-core:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-circularbuffer:jar:1.7.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-framework-common:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-circuitbreaker:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-ratelimiter:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-retry:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-bulkhead:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-timelimiter:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-micrometer:jar:1.7.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-reactor:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.5.3:provided (optional)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.5.3:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-inline:jar:3.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.22:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.22:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.5.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.5.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.19.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.9:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:5.5.1:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:6.10.4:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:6.10.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:jar:6.10.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin-messages:jar:6.10.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:messages:jar:15.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:10.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:3.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-plugin:jar:6.10.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:docstring:jar:6.10.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:html-formatter:jar:13.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.cucumber:create-meta:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:jar:6.10.4:test
[INFO] |  \- net.jodah:typetools:jar:0.6.3:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:jar:6.10.4:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:jar:6.10.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] +- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:4.1.0:test
[INFO] +- org.testcontainers:testcontainers:jar:1.16.0:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.rnorth.duct-tape:duct-tape:jar:1.0.8:test
[INFO] |  +- com.github.docker-java:docker-java-api:jar:3.2.11:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.docker-java:docker-java-transport-zerodep:jar:3.2.11:test
[INFO] |     +- com.github.docker-java:docker-java-transport:jar:3.2.11:test
[INFO] |     \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.8.0:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.7.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.kafka:connect-json:jar:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.kafka:connect-api:jar:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:jar:5.18.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:jar:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-raft:jar:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.13:jar:2.12.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2.12.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-collection-compat_2.13:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.13:jar:0.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.13.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.13.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.13:jar:3.9.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.5.9:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper-jute:jar:3.5.9:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.66.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.66.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:test:2.7.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] +- io.projectreactor:reactor-test:jar:3.4.8:test
[INFO] |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] \- com.konghq:unirest-java:jar:3.11.11:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:test
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.13:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.14:test
[INFO]    \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.4:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.163 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-01T14:22:24+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you first explain why you add mockito-inline? Because I don't see any need for that?

Comment: You are right, It is for the purpose of reproducing the problem.

Comment: No that's not the reason. Why do you need mockito-inline? That's the reason I'm asking for...